# Android: Set Text View's text from another activity Not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 activities and 2 classes.

In my Main class, when i click submit button it will start another activity. here is the code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
    newActivity.setViewValues(fNameET.getText().toString(), lNameET.getText().toString(), mInitialET.getText().toString(), "Female", "birthday", addressET.getText().toString(), cNumberET.getText().toString());   
}
```

The newActivity is an object of the other activity and the setViewValues is the method of it.

This doesn't work, this is how i do it in java gui. Maybe something is missing.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: use intent for sending values to next Activity and call setViewValues method in oncreate of NewActivity to set new values to UI elements instead of calling Activity methods by create Activity object .

Comment: yes you can pass parameters in Bundle and assign them in onCreate()

Comment: You should not try to call one activity from another.  One activity at a time.

Comment: @Simon Thats the only way I know now on how to switch windows or activities.

Comment: You can start one Activity from another, with an Intent.  This is absolutely the right way.  What I meant is that one Activity should not try to access anything in another.  You cannot do something like activityA = new ActivtyA(); activityA.doSomething();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the data like this.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
intent.putExtra("firstName",fvalue);
intent.putExtra("lastname",lname);
......
startActivity(intent);
```

**NewActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");
    String lastName = intent.getStringExtra("lastname");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the application crashes. Should I put that code for the NewActivity in the onCreate method?

Comment: @Katherine try now let me know what is exception first try this

Comment: Thank you. This is perfectly working. The crash before was caused by other errors.